# "Recipient address rejected" when sending an email with sendgrid

Tags: postfix

In postfix, I'm using `relay_host` to send an email to an external address using `sendgrid`, but I get an error about local ricipient table when sending an email from my PHP code.

This is my `main.cf` in `/postfix/`

```
## -- Sendgrid
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:username:password 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous 
smtp_tls_security_level = may 
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

This is the error message from the log:

```
postfix/smtpd[53598]: [ID 197553 mail.info] NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<help@mydomain.com> to=<john@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain>
```

One interesting thing is when I use "sendmail john@mydomain.com" from the command line, the email is delivered successfully using SendGrid. I think it's because this uses postfix/smtp instead of postfix/smtpD

the log for this says,

postfix/smtp[18670]: [ID 197553 mail.info] AAF7313A7E: to=, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[50.97.69.148]:587, delay=4.1, delays=3.5/0.02/0.44/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Delivery in progress)

Thank you

Comment: Check your formatting please. You have to indent code by 4 spaces or press `Ctrl-K` for it to display correctly.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. The error I see in `/var/log/mail.log` is
`Feb  3 22:57:29 vsempprdapp11 postfix/error[24019]: 327A4441481: to=<DistU_MyAdmin@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=193633, delays=193632/1/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)`